# Always EXC_BAD_ACCESS on SecTrustEvaluate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, validation, x509certificate, evaluation

I am using [Apple's example code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html) for evaluating a X509 certificate. 
I have modified a bit to obtain a certificate from my bundle (only changed the file name).

When I run this it always crashes in the line with `comment 5` `status = SecTrustEvaluate(myTrust, &trustResult);`. I get an always `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` there.

```
- (BOOL)validateCertificate
{
    NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"user_signed_cert" ofType:@"crt"];
    NSData *certData = [[NSData alloc]
                        initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
    CFDataRef myCertData = (__bridge_retained CFDataRef)certData; //1
    SecCertificateRef myCert;
    myCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, myCertData); //2
    SecPolicyRef myPolicy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509(); //3
    SecCertificateRef certArray[1] = { myCert };
    CFArrayRef myCerts = CFArrayCreate(
                                       NULL, (void *)certArray,
                                       1, NULL);
    SecTrustRef myTrust;
    OSStatus status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(
                                                     myCerts,
                                                     myPolicy,
                                                     &myTrust); //4
    SecTrustResultType trustResult;
    if (status == noErr) {
        status = SecTrustEvaluate(myTrust, &trustResult); //5 }

        NSLog(@"Status: %d", status);
        //6 if (trustResult == kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure) {
    }

    if (myPolicy)
        CFRelease(myPolicy);
}
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

**Update #1: I have changed it to the following but nothing changes. Same EXC_BAD_ACCESS on `SecTrustEvaluate()`.**

```
NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[temp addObject:certData];
OSStatus status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates((__bridge CFArrayRef)temp, myPolicy, &myTrust);
```

It seems that `status` is empty after `SecTrustCreateWithCertificates()` but does not contain an error.

Any other suggestions whats wrong?

**Update #2: I have tried the solution mentioned below and receive always `kSecTrustResultInvalid`. I have only changed the CA certificate creation to store the private key in `ca.key` because when signing the request (`client.csr`) I got the following error message:**

```
Signature ok
subject=/CN=foo-by-ZeeCA
Getting CA Private Key
unable to load CA Private Key
```

Furthermore I had to change the signing request command to `openssl x509 -CA ca.pem -in client.csr -CAkey ca.key -req -set_serial 1  -out client.pem`. (added `-CAkey ca.key`)

Then I have used the code in the solution below and added my paths from the bundle. Additionally, I have added a switch-case for the status.

```
/*
 # CA
 openssl req -x509 -new -subj /CN=ZeeCA -keyout ca.key -nodes -set_serial 1 > ca.pem
 openssl x509 -outform DER -out ca.der -in ca.pem

 # create andsign client
 openssl req  -new -subj /CN=foo-by-ZeeCA -CAkey ca.key  -keyout client.key -nodes > client.csr
 openssl x509 -CA ca.pem -in client.csr -req -set_serial 1  -out client.pem

 # format for client identity import
 openssl pkcs12 -export -out client.12 -inkey client.key -in client.pem -CAfile ca.pem -password pass:1234

 # format for trust.
 openssl x509 -in client.pem -out client.der -outform der

 */

NSString *clientPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"client" ofType:@"der"];

//NSString *thePath = @"XXXX/client.der";

NSData *certData = [[NSData alloc]
                    initWithContentsOfFile:clientPath];
CFDataRef myCertData = (__bridge_retained CFDataRef)certData; //1

assert(myCertData);

SecCertificateRef myCert;
myCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, myCertData); //2

assert(myCert);

SecPolicyRef myPolicy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509(); //3

NSArray * certArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(__bridge id)(myCert)];

SecTrustRef myTrust;
OSStatus status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(
                                                 (__bridge CFArrayRef)certArray,
                                                 myPolicy,
                                                 &myTrust); //4

NSString *caPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ca" ofType:@"der"];
NSData *caData = [[NSData alloc]
                  initWithContentsOfFile:caPath];
CFDataRef myCaData = (__bridge_retained CFDataRef)caData; 
SecCertificateRef myCA = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, myCaData); 
assert(myCA);

NSArray * myCAs = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(__bridge id)(myCA)];

SecTrustResultType xxx = SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(myTrust, (__bridge CFArrayRef)(myCAs));
if (xxx != noErr) {
    NSLog(@"SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates failed: %d", xxx);
}


SecTrustResultType trustResult;
if (status == noErr) {
    status = SecTrustEvaluate(myTrust, &trustResult); //5 }        
    NSLog(@"Status: %d", status);
}

if (myPolicy)
    CFRelease(myPolicy);

if (status == noErr) {
    status = SecTrustEvaluate(myTrust, &trustResult); //5 }

    switch (status) {
        case kSecTrustResultProceed: // 1
            NSLog(@"Proceed");
            break;
        case kSecTrustResultConfirm: // 2
            NSLog(@"Confirm");
            break;
        case kSecTrustResultUnspecified: // 4
            NSLog(@"Unspecified");
            break;
        case kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure:  // 5
            NSLog(@"TrustFailure");
            break;
        case kSecTrustResultDeny: // 3
            NSLog(@"Deny");
            break;
        case kSecTrustResultFatalTrustFailure: // 6
            NSLog(@"FatalTrustFailure");
            break;
        case kSecTrustResultOtherError: // 7
            NSLog(@"OtherError");
            break;
        case kSecTrustResultInvalid: // 0
            NSLog(@"Invalid");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Default");
            break;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is in the array of an array. I use the code below - i.e. pass a simple flat array of SecCertificateRef's in what you call myCerts.

```
        NSMutableArray *serverChain = [NSMutableArray array];
        for(int i = 0; i < SecTrustGetCertificateCount(secTrustRef); i++)
            [serverChain addObject:(__bridge id)(SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(secTrustRef,i))];

        SecTrustRef noHostTrustRef = NULL;
        OSErr status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates((__bridge CFArrayRef) serverChain, SecPolicyCreateSSL(NO, nil), &noHostTrustRef);


        if (status != noErr) {
            NSLog(@"SecTrustCreateWithCertificates failed: %hd", status);
            [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }

        NSMutableArray *certRefs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[acceptableCAs count]];
        for(Certificate * cert in acceptableCAs)
            [certRefs addObject:(id)[cert secCertificateRef]];

        status = SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(noHostTrustRef, (__bridge CFArrayRef)certRefs);
        if (status != noErr) {
            NSLog(@"SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates failed: %hd", status);
            [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }

        status = SecTrustEvaluate(noHostTrustRef, &result);
        if (status != noErr) {
            NSLog(@"SecTrustEvaluate failed: %hd", status);
            [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
        CFRelease(noHostTrustRef);
```

If I take your code and put it in a simple cmd line wrapper:

## import

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

```
@autoreleasepool {

    //  openssl req -x509 -new -subj /CN=foo -out user_signed_cert.crt \
    //      -keyout /dev/null -outform DER -nodes -set_serial 1
    //
    NSString *thePath = @"XXXXX/user_signed_cert.crt";

    NSData *certData = [[NSData alloc]
                        initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
    CFDataRef myCertData = (__bridge_retained CFDataRef)certData; //1

    assert(myCertData);

    SecCertificateRef myCert;
    myCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, myCertData); //2
    SecPolicyRef myPolicy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509(); //3
    SecCertificateRef certArray[1] = { myCert };
    CFArrayRef myCerts = CFArrayCreate(
                                       NULL, (void *)certArray,
                                       1, NULL);
    SecTrustRef myTrust;
    OSStatus status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(
                                                     myCerts,
                                                     myPolicy,
                                                     &myTrust); //4
    SecTrustResultType trustResult;
    if (status == noErr) {
        status = SecTrustEvaluate(myTrust, &trustResult); //5 }

        NSLog(@"Status: %d", status);
        //6 if (trustResult == kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure) {
    }

    if (myPolicy)
        CFRelease(myPolicy);

}
return 0;
```

and with an explicit cert:

```
@autoreleasepool {

    /*

     # CA
     openssl req -x509 -new -subj /CN=ZeeCA -keyout /dev/stdout -nodes -set_serial 1 > ca.pem
     openssl x509 -outform DER -out ca.der -in ca.pem

     # create andsign client
     openssl req  -new -subj /CN=foo-by-ZeeCA   -keyout client.key -nodes > client.csr
     openssl x509 -CA ca.pem -in client.csr -req -set_serial 1  -out client.pem

     # format for client identity import
     openssl pkcs12 -export -out client.12 -inkey client.key -in client.pem -CAfile ca.pem -password pass:1234

     # format for trust.
     openssl x509 -in client.pem -out client.der -outform der

     */
    NSString *thePath = @"XXXX/client.der";

    NSData *certData = [[NSData alloc]
                        initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
    CFDataRef myCertData = (__bridge_retained CFDataRef)certData; //1

    assert(myCertData);

    SecCertificateRef myCert;
    myCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, myCertData); //2

    assert(myCert);

    SecPolicyRef myPolicy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509(); //3

    NSArray * certArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(__bridge id)(myCert)];

    SecTrustRef myTrust;
    OSStatus status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(
                                                     (__bridge CFArrayRef)certArray,
                                                     myPolicy,
                                                     &myTrust); //4


    NSData *caData = [[NSData alloc]
                       initWithContentsOfFile:@"XXXXX/ca.der"];
    CFDataRef myCaData = (__bridge_retained CFDataRef)caData; 
    SecCertificateRef myCA = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, myCaData); 
    assert(myCA);

    NSArray * myCAs = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(__bridge id)(myCA)];

    SecTrustResultType xxx = SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(myTrust, (__bridge CFArrayRef)(myCAs));
    if (xxx != noErr) {
        NSLog(@"SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates failed: %d", xxx);
    }


    SecTrustResultType trustResult;
    if (status == noErr) {
        status = SecTrustEvaluate(myTrust, &trustResult); //5 }

        NSLog(@"Status: %d", status);
        //6 if (trustResult == kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure) {
    }

    if (myPolicy)
        CFRelease(myPolicy);

}
```

both seem to do the trick for me ?

Comment: updated the answer - am wondering if your files are happy and/or of the correct format. included some openssl to rule that out.

Comment: Thanks, it works! It seems that my certificate creation was wrong. (`openssl x509 -CA ca.pem -in user.csr -req -set_serial 1 -outform DER -out user.der -CAkey CA.key`)

Comment: Additionally, when I check the result (`status`) it tells me the certificate is invalid. Basically, when I import the CA cert into my device (for example via email) and confirm that it is trustworthy the evaluation should succeed? I am asking because I have tried this and it still evaluates to invalid?!

Comment: Correct. And as far as I know - the iPhone needs the certificate to verify against as DER and the certificate to use for client auth as P12. If you wan to verify against the same cert as to use for client auth - then I found I need to seperately import it as a DER (sans private key of course) in order to -also- use it for trust.

Comment: This means that when I pack the users' certificate (`user_signed_cert.der`) and his key (`user_key.key`) into a pkcs12 container (using `openssl pkcs12 ...`) then I can just import it as mentioned before (by simply setting `thePath` to the .p12 file) and it should work? I am going to try this tomorrow! Thanks!

Comment: right. but it seems that *MUST* set a password of as far as I can work out at least for chars. And once importat as an identity that way - it gets ignored for trust it seems. But also importing it keyless as DER seems to nicely do trust. I'll update above to add p12 create.

Comment: Okay, I have tried your code (with also your openssl commands) and for me it does not work? Can it fail because I am using it on the device directly and not in the simulator? I guess not.. I have updated my question above and included **all** my code and changes. Can you try to run my code on your device? I am totally confused...